# Probability that the bridge hands of North and South contain exactly $k$ aces

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

I have a rather elementary question about problem II.31 in Feller's introduction to probability theory and applications.

> What is the probability that the bridge hands of North and South together contain exactly $k$ aces, where $k=0,1,2,3,4$?

**The solution given in the book is** :

There are $4 \choose k$ ways to select $k$ aces out of $4$. There are $48 \choose 26 - k$ ways to select non-ace cards. The required probability $p$ equals:

$$p={4 \choose k}{48 \choose 26-k}/{52 \choose 26}$$

I understand that we are indifferent to how many aces each player individually gets. We are interested in the probability of a $26$-card hand with $k$ aces.

**My Solution.**

What I did was to write my solution as:

\begin{align*}
    & \sum_{l=0}^{k}{4 \choose l}{48 \choose 13 - l}{4 - l \choose k - l}{48 - (13 -l) \choose 13 - (k - l)}/{52 \choose 13}{39 \choose 13}
\end{align*}

**Inference.**

In the denominator, I see that, ${52 \choose 13}{39 \choose 13} \ne {52 \choose 26}$. I inferred that the number of $26$-card hands for **north and south together** are lesser than the number of $13$-card hands for north and $13$-card hands for south. North getting a Ace of heart and South getting an ace of spade is the same as North getting a ace of spade and South getting an ace of hearts. If I divide by $(2!)^{13}$, the denominator in my solution would equal the solution in the book.

**Question.**

1. I am not sure, how I one can account for overcounting in the numerator. I know that, $\sum_{k=0}^{r}{w \choose k}{n-w \choose r-k}={n \choose r}$.
2. The questions in Feller are clever. I get a few right, but I also get some of them wrong. How do I get better at it?

Comment: $$\binom{52}{26}\binom{26}{13}=\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}$$ The second approach has a sample space of $\binom{26}{13}$ elements for every sample spaces of the first space.

Comment: So you can think of the first answer as $$\frac{\binom{4}k\binom{48}{26-k}\binom{26}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}}$$

Comment: I upvoted - As for to how to improve - Just keep doing what you are doing.  That is, look for ways to *stretch your intuition*, which is a **key weapon** in problems involving probability &/or combinatorics.

Answer (score 1):

as to why the denominator isn't ${52 \choose13}$${39 \choose13}$: you don't usually distribute 13 cards to one player and then 13 cards to the other from the remaining 39. Instead, you distribute cards one at a time to each player until everyone playing has thirteen. So, in a two-player game, you distribute one card each until you have distributed 26, which is equivalent to distributing 26 all at once. Hence, the denominator is ${52 \choose26}$.

And w.r.t. to your numerator; a tip I would give you is to pretend like you are **giving** 2 aces, say, to player one (you can do this in ${4 \choose2}$ ways.) Then go on to **give** player 1 the rest of his hand from the remaining 48 cards (which can be done in ${48 \choose12}$ ways.)

I highlight give because it forces you to distribute cards in a particular way, which makes getting to the solution a lot easier than if you try to go about it in the regular way.